# Replacing XML nodes using perl and Mojo::DOM

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I would like to exchange node in an XML file using [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM). 
I'm pretty sure it is possible but I didn't find a way yet.

Given the following XML:

```
my $xml = q~
<html>
    <div>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <img />
    </div>
</html>
~;
```

I would like to remove the div and instead insert a body tag, so that the result looks like this:

```
my $xml = q~
<html>
    <body>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <img />
    </body>
</html>
~;
```

I thought about replace, but I didn't find an example where the replacement is the $dom of the replaced tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to just find the `<div>` element and use the `tag` method to change its tag

This program demonstrates. The CSS selector `html > div` finds the (first) `<div>` element that is a child of an `<html>` element

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $xml = q~
<html>
    <div>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <img />
    </div>
</html>
~;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($xml);

$dom->at('html > div')->tag('body');

print $dom, "\n";
```

**output**

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <img>
        </body>
    </html>
```